# Python itertools.product with arbitrary number of sets

Tags: python, product, python-itertools

I wish to execute the following code:

```
temp = []
temp.append([1,2])
temp.append([3,4])
temp.append([5,6])

print list(itertools.product(temp[0],temp[1],temp[2]))
```

However, I would like to execute it for temp with arbitrary length. I.e. something more like:

```
print list(itertools.product(temp))
```

How do I format the input correctly for itertools.product to produce the same result in the first segment of code without explicitly knowing how many entries there are in temp?

Answer (score 3):

```
print list(itertools.product(*temp))
```

Use `*` to unpack the argument iterable as separate positional arguments.

Comment: Apologies, found the solution after a bit more searching. And now can't delete. Sorry!

Comment: @user2331057 No need to delete - posting the solution you found as an answer was the correct thing to do.  Now accept your own answer if it solved your problem satisfactorily.

Comment: @Brionius: I'm not the OP. Our usernames look very similar, but you can see that our rep counts are different and his name has a blue background.

Answer (score 0):

Or can do that:

Combine lists using zip. 
The result is a list itertator.

```
a = ["A", "a"]
b = ["B", "b"]
c = ["C", "c"]

number_iterator = zip(a,b,c)
numbers = list(number_iterator)

print (numbers)
```